# Importing a large query with a large extended insert to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

Is there any program or script that can break down a extended insert (about 380,000 rows) into single SQL queries, my hosting isn't handling it and I found a script called Big Dump that imports single quires but it doesn't work for extended quires.

Comment: If possible, you could use `mysql -u USER -p DBNAME < dump.sql`

Comment: into hosting which isn't able to handle 380 000 queries?

Comment: If you have the SQl file with you , modify your local phpmyadmin suitably to be able to upload large files , and import into local db then export from php my admin with single queries

Comment: Kantu, what do you modify in my.cnf to change the max import size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$lines = file('file.txt');
$count = count($lines);
$i = 0;
$query = "INSERT INTO table VALUES ";
foreach($lines as $line){
    $i++;
    if ($count == $i) {
        $query .= "('".$line."')";
    }
    else{
        $query .= "('".$line."'),";
    }
}
mysql_query($query);
```

be sure it is not out of limit set in my.cnf